# Adding Headers On A Specific Pattern in a File

Tags: linux, text-processing

I  have a file in which I need to add a header on multiple locations in linux. The 'header' is a file and I can add it only at first row; and that's fine but I want to add it now the same header on multiple locations; specifically before a new  IP address is found. I actaully dont need a file with the header; I can just simply add the text via awk or sed after having all the output.

The header needs to be inserted exactly after a new IP address is found.

The list is variable; for example at ip 192.168.10.10 there are here 3 entries but it could be lot more; and for ip 192.168.10.33 for example there are 2 entries but could be lot more. The ports by default are already sorted; but the IP Addresses are not sorted but its already group.

Output looks like:

```
192.168.10.10    1/1/2
192.168.10.10    1/1/3
192.168.10.10    1/1/4
192.168.10.33    1/1/2
192.168.10.33    1/1/6
192.168.10.20    1/1/6
192.168.10.20    1/1/7
192.168.10.20    1/1/10
192.168.10.20    1/1/18
```

I want the output looks like this:

```
SWITCH ID        PORT    
192.168.10.10    1/1/2
192.168.10.10    1/1/3
192.168.10.10    1/1/4

SWITCH ID        PORT              
192.168.10.33    1/1/2
192.168.10.33    1/1/6

SWITCH ID        PORT
192.168.10.20    1/1/6
192.168.10.20    1/1/7
192.168.10.20    1/1/10
192.168.10.20    1/1/18
```

Answer (score 1):

here is rather verbosely written awk script which adds the header

```
NR==1 {
  print "SWITCH ID        PORT"
  print $0
  prev=$1
  next
}
$1!=prev {
  print ""
  print "SWITCH ID        PORT"
  print $0
  prev=$1
  next
}
$1==prev {
  print $0
}
```

save this to a file. for example `addheader.awk`

invoke like this

```
awk -f addheader.awk inputfile
```

or like this

```
commandproducinginput | awk -f addheader.awk
```

explanation of the script

awk works roughly like this:

```
for every line of input
  for every rule
    if condition is true
      execute code block
```

a "rule" is a pair of a condition and a code block.

an example of a rule from the code above

```
NR==1 {
  print "SWITCH ID        PORT"
  print $0
  prev=$1
  next
}
```

the `NR==1` is the condition. the part in the curly braces `{...}` is the code block.

`NR` is an awk specific variable containing the line number (the record number to be exact). so `NR==1` is true on the first line only.

on the first line we print a header line. then print the actual line (`$0` is the awk variable for current line). then remember the IP adress of this line (`$1` is the awk variable for first field of current line). then we say to go directly to next line so the other rules are not considered by awk. you can think of `next` like a `break` out of the `for every rule` loop.

the condition of the next rule `$1!=prev` is true if the current IP adress does not match the previous adress. in this case we print an empty line. then the header. then the line itself. then remember this new IP adress. then to go to the next line.

the last rule is the "default case". if the IP adress is the same as the previous then just print the line as is.

the `next` in the preceding rules effectively form an if else if chain.

in pseudo code it looks roughly like this

```
for every line:
  if is first line:
    print header then line
  else if IP adress is different than previous:
    print empty line then header then line
  else if IP adress is same to previous:
    print line
```

---

bonus:

the following variants are equivalent

omit the last code block

```
NR==1 {
  print "SWITCH ID        PORT"
  print $0
  prev=$1
  next
}
$1!=prev {
  print ""
  print "SWITCH ID        PORT"
  print $0
  prev=$1
  next
}
$1==prev
```

if the code block is missing the default action is to print the line as is.

alternatively omit the condition but keep the code block

```
NR==1 {
  print "SWITCH ID        PORT"
  print $0
  prev=$1
  next
}
$1!=prev {
  print ""
  print "SWITCH ID        PORT"
  print $0
  prev=$1
  next
}
{
  print $0
}
```

if the condition is missing it is implicit true. this is possible because of the `next` in the preceding rules which effectively form an if else if chain. the last rule is like the last else so it does not need any condition.

reorder the rules

```
$1==prev
NR==1 {
  print "SWITCH ID        PORT"
  print $0
  prev=$1
}
$1!=prev {
  print ""
  print "SWITCH ID        PORT"
  print $0
  prev=$1
}
```

like this we can leave out the `next`. but for my taste it is not as readable.

extract common code to a function

```
func common() {
  print "SWITCH ID        PORT"
  print $0
  prev=$1
  next
}
NR==1 {
  common()
}
$1!=prev {
  print ""
  common()
}
$1==prev
```

note that all variables are global in awk.

Comment: +1 For the evolutionary method described. Good for the beginning folks starring out in Awk on how to think in this language.

Comment: Amazing explanation +10!!!! Im very happy for that; Appreciated!.. Just didnt worked becuase I already have the output file created. The awk you did; looks that it needs an input to be able to generate the output I want. I tried the awk in different part the my code but it displays only once. I may be doing something wrong. It is possible to manipulate the output? I have a small code but cant paste it here....

Comment: yes the awk script needs input. you pipe the input to the awk script and capture the output for further use. you can use it either like this: `awk -f addheader.awk listwithoutheader > listwithheader` or like this `commandthatisproducinglist | awk -f addheader.awk > listwithheader`. if you still have problem then ask another question.

Comment: Hi.. Same issue. It displays only the first row. 
I tried this: cat output.txt | awk -f ap_header.awk output.txt > output2.txt
and also tried this: awk -f ap_header.awk output.txt > output2.txt

The output looks like this:
SWITCH ID       PORT
192.168.10.10   1/1/2

It injects the first row of header; but with only a single output line. Maybe my code is awful.

Comment: are you running this on windows or mac? the different line endings might cause awk to mess up. if yes you need to convert the line endings to the one that awk understands. either way if you still have problems you should ask another question as this seems to be too big to solve in comments.

Comment: Hi. Im running it directly on a Ubuntu Server. So there is no VM.